# Javascript Timer pauses while confirm-popup is shown

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to create a shoppingcart with reservation time. The remaining time gets calculated by php. As the user enters the requested page, the time gets executed with the integer of seconds, that comes from php (session). If there are 3 minutes left, javascript starts a confirm-box and asks the user, if he wants to reset the timer to go on with his cart.

While the confirm-box is shown, the execution of the timer gets paused. How can I change my code, so that the timer runs without pausing it by the confirm-box?

```
//Starting the Counter in the document.ready-block
//remainingSeconds($_SESSION['timer']) is the time left in seconds (as int)
CountDownTimer('<?php echo remainingSeconds($_SESSION['timer']); ?>', 'reservedTime');
```

And here is the CountDownTimer function:

```
// These functions are located in an external .js-file
// Found it on StackOverflow and edited it for my needs
function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    if(id == "kill") {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        var _second = 1,
            _minute = _second * 60,
            _hour = _minute * 60;

        function showRemaining() {
            var time = dt--,
                minutes,
                seconds;

            if (dt == 180) {
                var extend = confirm("Reset the timer?");
                if (extend) {
                    resetCounter();
                }
            }

            if (dt < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '00:00';
                alert("No time left.");
                //--redirect for readability removed--
                return;
            }

            if(time > 59) {
                minutes = Math.floor((time % _hour) / _minute);
                seconds = Math.floor((time % _minute) / _second);
            } else {
                minutes = "0";
                seconds = time;
            }

            if(minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes}
            if(seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds}
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    }
}


function resetCounter() {
    request = $.ajax({url: "php/ajax.php?f=3"});
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        try {
            var data = $.parseJSON(response);
            CountDownTimer('0', 'kill'); // reset old counter
            CountDownTimer(data.time, 'reservedTime'); // start new one
        } catch(e) {
            alert("ERROR ERMAGERD");
            return false;
        }
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("ERROR");
    });

}
```

As the timer gets paused, it will create a time that differs from that in the session. So the cart might expire - but the user won't notice it and might lose his reserved items.

Edit: Or is there a better/secure method to integrate a shopping cart timer with output to the user, so that there won't be a time difference?

Comment: I think its not possible because of single threaded nature of JavaScript. i.e when your alert/confirm box is getting executed everything else will stop running(including your timer function). Best you can do is implement custom alert/confirm box which is generally based on pop-up div/box

Comment: That's a good point. Made a custom alert-/confirm-div. Thanks!